# How do we use stream and convert commands together in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I do understand from the imagemagick documentation that we do use stream command for processing large images.

[Imagemagick Stream Interface](https://imagemagick.org/script/stream.php)

The question i have is: how do we use the stream command in conjunction with the convert command. Can we pipe the output of stream command to convert command or stream alone should be sufficient to achieve the needed transformations (eg: crop and resize)

Can someone provide any sample command ?? or maybe some material where i can find this ? let us say for a crop and resize use case ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did some timings of various ways to extract a 100x100 area from the bottom-right corner of a 12000x10000 image then resize it to 50x50 and save.

Make 200MB JPEG

```
magick -size 12000x10000 xc: +noise random a.jpg
```

Crop and resize with straight ImageMagick:

```
time magick a.jpg -crop 100x100+8000+8000 -resize 50 result.jpg
real    0m 2.38s
user    0m 2.10s
sys     0m 0.27s
```

Crop and resize with `stream`:

```
time magick stream -storage-type char -map rgb -extract 100x100+8000+8000 a.jpg - | magick -depth 8 -size 100x100 rgb:- -resize 50 result.jpg
real    0m 2.04s
user    0m 1.98s
sys     0m 0.05s
```

Crop and resize with `vips`:

```
time  vips extract_area a.jpg .ppm 8000 8000  100 100 | vipsthumbnail --size 50x50 -o result.jpg stdin 
real    0m 1.61s
user    0m 1.52s
sys     0m 0.08s
```

My conclusion is that there is little benefit to using `stream` in this case, and that `vips` is somewhat faster.

---

The TIFF format allows images to be saved in strips that an image processor can seek to, without reading all the intermediate stuff. This is helpful when extracting chunks not near the start of images. So I made a TIFF with `rows-per-strip=500`

```
magick -size 12000x10000 xc: +noise random -depth 8 -define tiff:rows-per-strip=500 a.tif
```

Then I repeated the 3 tests from above:

Crop and resize with straight ImageMagick:

```
time magick a.tif -crop 100x100+8000+8000 -resize 50 result.jpg
real    0m 0.83s
user    0m 0.44s
sys     0m 0.38s
```

Crop and resize with `stream`:

```
time magick stream -storage-type char -map rgb -extract 100x100+8000+8000 a.tif - | magick -depth 8 -size 100x100 rgb:- -resize 50 result.jpg
real    0m 0.82s
user    0m 0.44s
sys     0m 0.38s
```

Crop and resize with `vips`:

```
time  vips extract_area a.tif .ppm 8000 8000  100 100 | vipsthumbnail --size 50x50 -o result.jpg stdin 
real    0m 0.17s
user    0m 0.05s
sys     0m 0.12s
```

My conclusion is that there is a definite benefit to using TIFF format and `vips` if you are trying to do this sort of thing.